# Most efficient way to find the indexes of unique values in a Python 3 list

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the *most efficient* way to find the indexes of strings in a list that occur only once?

```
foo = ['it', 'does', 'it', 'very', 'very', 'well']
bar = ???  # bar = [1, 5]
```

I already know about sets, dictionaries and list comprehensions.  The problem I'm trying to solve here is in my production code I have parallel data lists where the index of one is the index of many which can't be changed for historical reasons.

Comment: Why the close votes as "too broad"?  I thought it was well-targeted question that currently has only one good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [**collections.Counter**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects) subclass:

```
import collections

foo = ['it', 'does', 'it', 'very', 'very', 'well']
counts = collections.Counter(foo)
result = [i for i,v in enumerate(foo) if counts[v] == 1]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[1, 5]
```

Comment: Just curious : Why do you mention it's a subclass? Isn't (almost) every class in Python a subclass?

Comment: @EricDuminil, sometimes, I cite from documentation: *A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects.*. (of course, every class is a sublcass, except topmost ABC)

Comment: Okay, it sure makes sense if you specify Counter's superclass. Nice answer BTW.

Answer (score 0):

You will get what you want. Dictionaries are faster in python

```
from collections import Counter
foo = ['it', 'does', 'it', 'very', 'very', 'well']
d = dict(Counter(foo))
[i for i,v in enumerate(foo) if counts[v]  == 1]
```

You can also use set(foo)

Comment: There's already an answer with counter. Plus, this code outputs the unique words, not their indices.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, especially if the size of your foo list is bigger than in your example above and have lots of duplicates.

```
seen = set()
[i for i,e in enumerate(foo) if not (e in seen or seen.add(e) or e in foo[i+1:])]
```

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the kind of efficiency you would like to get. You could do this directly in a list comprehension, straightforward and readable:

> bar = [index for index,el in enumerate(foo) if foo.count(el)==1]

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600191/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-list-item-in-python) for info if you would like to use Counter